# Random objects from Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

A query regarding arrays in JavaScript: 
//**colors** only works when quoted, reason? I am getting an Array like this and need to pass the random values from following colors array to my URL, but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display a random number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

//**num** works both ways, even when they are quoted or if I use the commented line.
var num = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','6');
//var num = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6);

//**colors** only works when quoted, reason? I am getting an Array like this and need to pass the random values from following colors array to my URL, but it doesn't work.

var colors= new Array('red','blue','green','orange','cyan','yellow', 'black');
//var colors= new Array(red,blue,green,orange,cyan,yellow, black);

var item = num [Math.floor(Math.random()*num .length)];
var item2= colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=item +" : "+ item2;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because numbers will be cast to strings, but strings cannot be represented as numbers. Without quotes they're not string literals, but variable names and will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting an Array like this"?

Comment: I am getting an array as colors(red, blue, green, black)
So it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var num = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','6');
> ```

That's an array of string literals that contain numbers.

> ```
> var num = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6);
> ```

That's an array of number literals.

> ```
> var colors= new Array('red','blue','green','orange','cyan','yellow', 'black');
> ```

That's an array of string literals.

> ```
> var colors= new Array(red,blue,green,orange,cyan,yellow, black);
> ```

That's an array of variables.

The numbers will be automatically stringified when concatenated with the `" : "` string and therefore work like number strings, but your variables will just throw `Undefined Variable` exceptions.

Comment: Whats the fix for this?